# How to Implement a Custom Health Check for Flink Task Managers to Automatically Restart on Connectivity Issues?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I recently encountered a problem with our Flink Task Managers running in a Kubernetes environment managed by the Flink Kubernetes Operator. These Task Managers intermittently lost connectivity to an S3 storage service. While this issue was resolved by manually restarting the Task Managers, it's not a sustainable solution. To proactively handle such connectivity issues, I want to create a custom health check for Flink Task Managers that will automatically restart them when connectivity problems arise.

Any guidance or code examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!